# Link listings with image

Tags: images, widgets

So I'm really new to Wordpress and I'm trying to create a simple widget.  I want the widget to list the logos of my site's affiliates (similar to the "check out our shows" section on http://www.howstuffworks.com/).

I also want it to be easy for the administrators to add/remove images from the list of partners.  In other words, I don't want to have to modify the widget's code in order to change the partners.

At a very high level what are the steps that I might follow to build this widget?

Comment: @Diana's suggestion is very good. But regarding the [widget building](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), you'd have to present some code and what you're trying to do that involves *`Getting images by metadata`*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [Links Categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Links_Manager)? There you can use images, descriptions, create categories and sort out everything. There would be no need to create a widget as you can use the default WordPress one.

[image: links widget]

Case you were to create your own widget, you can query these items with WordPress functions.

Comment: @Pace : And case you were to follow this route, this plugin of mine can be handy: [Featured Link Image](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/featured-link-image/). (WPSE born:) . . . . And other useful plugin for that: [My Link Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/my-link-order/) . . . .

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly what I'm looking for.  @brasofilo I will look into those plugins as well.